# Sometimes the position in getItemViewType(int position) is -1 when i remove an object from recylerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

remove method:

```
public CustomObject remove(int adapterPos) {
    CustomObject customObject = customObjects.remove(adapterPos); //arraylist of custom objects
    notifyItemRemoved(adapterPos);
    return customObject;
}
```

Then the position inside `getItemViewType(int position)` is `-1` instead of a valid position.

If I change `notifyItemRemoved(adapterPos);` to `notifyDataSetChanged();` the problem doesn't arise

Also, it works sometimes. When it does work, the correct item is removed.

Comment: What is the question and can you add the logs and little clarity on scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Android Studio open in front of me currently but `-1` is usually a default value for something that's invalid. If you remove the item from the `RecyclerView.Adapter` and then try to get the type of that view it should indicate that it's not valid. When you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` it lets the Adapter know that the data has changed and it should update, so that's why you would no longer see `-1`.

Honestly I wouldn't worry about this return value, if you are removing a item you probably shouldn't be getting its viewtype.